# Regular Expression Search On String

Tags: java, regex

I am having great issues searching a string for particular parameters that are needed in my application, I am under the assumption that the only real way to do this is using regular expressions however they are giving me a huge headache! I don't usually write them myself but get them off other websites however what i need isn't simple enough to be included :(

Here is the string:

```
10 50 u E2U+pstn:tel "!^(.*)$!tel:\\1;spn=42180;mcc=234;mnc=33!" .
```

I need to extract the `spn`, `mcc`, and the `mnc` from this string. Unfortunately the api i call changes the location of these on the string for some requests which makes indexing the string difficult. I really need to list what i need to grab the spn= for example then follow off and read the number but everything i try never works.

Comment: Why not study a little bit of regular expressions? Constructing one for this should be trivial after following this tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
String s = "10 50 u E2U+pstn:tel \"!^(.*)$!tel:\\\\1;spn=42180;mcc=234;mnc=33!\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*spn=([0-9]+);mcc=([0-9]*);mnc=([0-9]*)!.*$");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
matcher.matches(); // true
String spn = matcher.group(1); // 42180
String mcc = matcher.group(2); // 234
String mnc = matcher.group(3); // 33
```

**Edit:** You can use [named-capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname), too:

```
Pattern p =
  Pattern.compile("^.*spn=(?<spn>[0-9]+);mcc=(?<mcc>[0-9]*);mnc=(?<mnc>[0-9]*)!.*$");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
matcher.matches(); // true
String spn = matcher.group("spn");
String mcc = matcher.group("mcc");
String mnc = matcher.group("mnc");
```

Comment: I don't think this would work if the order of parameters change (*"Unfortunately the api i call changes the location of these on the string"*)

Comment: Good point. But it should be easy to use three patterns, one for each group.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use regex but simply splitting :

```
String[] tokens = str.split(";");
for (int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
   if (tokens[i].startsWith("spn=")) {
       spn = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i].substring("spn=".length()));
   }
}
```

Of course you could objectify this a little, or use constants for `"spn="`.